# How to add different style fonts to footer of webpage

Tags: html, css

I am very new to the coding world and this is my first time posting. I've been teaching myself how to code for about two weeks now. I'm working on coding up a dummy site and the footer has two styles of text (Montserrat Bold & Galada).

I've attached an image so you can see what I'm talking about.

[image: Footer text]

I typed it up in the HTML like this:

```
<footer>
<p>POWERED BY LOTS OF FRESH INGREDIENTS</p>
</footer>
```

Do I need to add a `<span>` before and after fresh and set the styles for that text in the CSS or is that completely wrong and do I need to do something different?

Thanks for your help. Really enjoying learning how to code!

Comment: That's correct. Did you try it? You'd have had an answer in a fraction of the time. :)

Comment: span would be fine and quite a usual way of highlighting individual words or phrases.

Comment: So the lesson here is that almost everything to do with HTML and CSS has already been asked. We love new questions, but we love making use of existing ones even more. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help everybody. I tried to and it didn't change it. I'm guessing I did something wrong in the CSS so that's why. Will go back and see what I did wrong.